# DNS query for former local Domain

Tags: 17.10, dns

Since upgrading my System from 17.04 to 17.10, I have problems resolving domains my laptop has been online within:

I regularly use my laptop at home (homedomain.de) and at university (scc.kit.edu). Both domains are distributed via DNS to my laptop and show up in

```
nmcli device show wlp3s0 | grep DOM
IP4.DOMÄNE[1]:                          scc.kit.edu
```

While being at home, I cannot query any DNS Name in .kit.edu Domain, and vice versa. Monitoring the DNS traffic in wireshark, I see that the queries are modified before submitting:

```
dig A imap.kit.edu
```

will, when being at home, be send as:

```
DNS 93  Standard query 0xada9 A imap.kit.edu.homedomain.de OPT
```

.

```
dig A mail.homedomain.de
```

will, when being at university, be send twice as:

```
DNS 82  Standard query 0xa8b6 A mail.homedomain.de.kit.edu
DNS 86  Standard query 0x9ed8 A mail.homedomain.de.scc.kit.edu
```

Obviously the answers I receive are, that the Domains do not exist. Which is true.
Sending a query directly to a DNS Server (dig @8.8.8.8 imap.kit.edu) works fine.

Why does my system consider former local domains sill local, and appends them with the current local domain?? And how do I turn this off?